# How to add a text file contents into combo box where text file contains spaces?

Tags: java, string, swing, jcombobox, text-parsing

I want to add a text file contents in a Swing combo box.

I need each line as each element in combo box. But the file contain white space between words. So it is splitting on white space by separate elements.

I used `DefaultCombBoxModel` and `model.addElement`.

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
String.replace(" ", "_")
```

Comment: Please, paste your code.

Comment: If your using Scanner to read the file then don't use the Scanner#next() method. Use the Scanner#nextLine() method in conjunction with Scanner#hasNextLine() instead: `String line; jComboBox1.removeAllItems(); while (scan.hasNextLine()) { line = scan.nextLine(); if (line.trim().equals("")) { continue; } jComboBox1.addItem(line); }`.

Comment: @SurajGautam *"Please, paste your code"* No, please don't do that. Instead, prepare and post a [mre] as an [edit]. Suraj, a tip: note that `[mre]` in a comment auto-expands to [mre].

Comment: Oh, and to the OP: Hard code some 'lines' in a `String` so that the code can reproduce the problem without requiring I/O or external resources like a text file.

Comment: *"I need each line as each element in combo box."* So read the input by line (e.g. using a [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())) and put each line directly into the combo box model. AFAIU similar / same can be done using a `Scanner` as referenced by @DevilsHnd above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the follwing solution:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Filepath"));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        List<String> comboElmnts = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append(ls);
                comboElmnts.add(line);
            }
            for (String lineItem : comboElmnts) {
                System.out.println(lineItem);
            }

        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
```

You can make use of the comboElmts list items as your combo items.